# Find time variable in raster data

Tags: raster, netcdf

I have managed to open and intersect a gridded .nc file with spatial polygons for river basins. Unfortunately, I cannot find which variable indicates the month at when the values were measured. The file should contain monthly irrigated area data.

Here is my code to open the file

```
irrig_path <- "/Volumes/Transcend/Uni/ETH/International Political Economy/data/Huang Water Use/irrigation water use/"
irrig_name <- "cons_irr_h08.nc"
irrig_file <- paste(irrig_path, irrig_name, sep="")
irrig_r <- raster(irrig_file, varname="cons_irr")
irrig_r
```

Here is a link to the file

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ry68E_M3e0twpBn8V8NdwSsHKkERE3AR/view?usp=sharing
```

and a link to the article that published the data. I could not find any indication where the date is stored.

```
https://www.hydrol-earth-syst-sci.net/22/2117/2018/hess-22-2117-2018.pdf
```

This is an image of the content of the raster data once loaded into R

[image]

Comment: Looks like the irrigation file might be more readily accessible though https://www.hydrol-earth-syst-sci.net/22/2117/2018/hess-22-2117-2018-assets.html or https://zenodo.org/record/1209296#.W_t6d5NKgWo or https://zenodo.org/record/1209296/files/irrigation%20water%20use%20v2.7z?download=1

Comment: Yes, in fact that's the same file contained in the drive link

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the netcdf file with `ncdump -h cons_irr_h08.nc` indicates the dimensions of the file are 480 months by 64028 grid_num, with a level of abstraction from grid_num into lat, lon. The data is structured as a set of 64028 individual time series. I don't think this will easily parse into the raster package.

```
$ ncdump -h cons_irr_h08.nc 
netcdf cons_irr_h08 {
dimensions:
    grid_num = 64028 ;
    month = 480 ;
variables:
    double cons_irr(month, grid_num) ;
        cons_irr:units = "mm/month" ;
        cons_irr:description = "1. gridded irrigation consumption results: 64028 rows, 480 Months;2.the results is based on the outputs of H08 forcing by WFDEI" ;
    double lon(grid_num) ;
        lon:units = "degree" ;
    double lat(grid_num) ;
        lat:units = "degree" ;
    double month(month) ;
        month:units = "months since 1971-1" ;
}
```

Maybe use `library(ncdf4)` or `library(RNetCDF)` to deal with file more directly and consider it as spatial point data.

ETA:

Looking at the lat and lon variables with `library(ncdf4)` shows it is pretty sparse and you need some sort of interpolation tool to re-grid the data to a raster.

```
library(ncdf4)
ncin <- nc_open("cons_irr_h08.nc")

lon= ncvar_get(ncin,'lon')
lat= ncvar_get(ncin,'lat')

head(cbind(lat,lon))
       lat   lon
[1,] 32.75 60.75
[2,] 33.25 60.75
[3,] 33.75 60.75
[4,] 34.25 60.75
[5,] 29.75 61.25
[6,] 30.25 61.25

plot(lon,lat,type='p',pch='.')
```

[image: plot of datapoint locations]

The "remap the entire field" section from https://rpubs.com/markpayne/132500 or https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/35322/10229 or [How to make RASTER from irregular point data without interpolation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79062/how-to-make-raster-from-irregular-point-data-without-interpolation) might be of some help with this data.

Back to the time variable question, you can extract it directly with the `ncdf4` package:

```
library(ncdf4)
ncin <- nc_open("cons_irr_h08.nc")    
tvar= ncvar_get(ncin,'month')
```

... and then you could turn the numerics into dates with this trick adapted from https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/35322/10229 :

```
add.months= function(date,n) seq(date, by = paste (n, "months"), length = 2)[2]
times = as.Date(sapply(tvar-1,add.months,date=as.Date('1971-01-15')),origin='1970-01-01')

head(times)

[1] "1971-01-15" "1971-02-15" "1971-03-15" "1971-04-15" "1971-05-15" "1971-06-15"
```

Comment: Looking a little bit at the lat,lon variables, they do not seem to be in any sort of raster order.  I don't know the dataset, but to make a raster from random points, you have to do some sort of interpolation.

Comment: Your help is highly appreciated Dave X! If I now retrieve the variable cons_irr

         cons_irr <- ncvar_get(ncin, 'cons_irr')

Couldn't I now just simply make a spatialPointDataframe form the extracted lon, lat, times and cons_irr? If so, how could I do that?

Comment: I found this wesite here that shows how to do it but it doesn't show how to do it for several observations over time http://rspatial.org/spatial/rst/3-vectordata.html  
Can I assume that the first entry in cons_irr can be associated with the first two entries of cbind(lon, lat)?

Comment: I don't have the dataset handy anymore to test, but I think you can try  `n=1;xx=nc_varget(ncin,'cons_irr',start=c(n,1),count=c(1,-1))` to get the full time series associated with the first (n=1) point.  Or `n=1;xx=nc_varget(ncin,'cons_irr',start=c(1,n),count=c(-1,1))` to get all the points at times step n=1.